# htmlentities()'s double_encode parameter not behaving correctly?

Tags: php, textarea, html-entities

Hey guys, I'm trying to use htmlentities() to convert the characters in a textarea to html codes. The code I have right now looks like this:

```
 var_dump($colors);
 $colors= htmlentities($colors, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
 var_dump($colors);
```

which returns this:

```
    string(31) "• Red 
    • Green
    • Blue<br />"
    string(46) "&bull; Red 
    &bull; Green
    &bull; Blue&lt;br /&gt;"
```

I assumed passing `false` to the double_encode parameter would prevent `<br />` from being converted to `&lt;br /&gt;`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `double_encode` parameter prevents encoding existing html entities (e.g. `&bull;`).  `<br />` is *not* an html entity, so it gets encoded.

Comment: Ah man. I knew there was something I was overlooking. Thanks!

Comment: Alex's answer may be more useful w/regards to an actual *solution* for this though, so I +1'd it instead.

Comment: But the first var_dump() already outputs the string `<br/>`, so the original string contains already `&lt;br /&gt;` (otherwise var_dump would not show the string <br />, it had to show a  line-break).

Comment: Only if you're viewing the output in a web browser.

Comment: As the OP only indicates that they're calling `htmlentities` once, we're assuming that's how many times they've called it.

Comment: He's correct. The string was copied from Fiddler so it originally contained the <br />

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a `"\n"` instead of a `<br />` inside your `textarea`.

To automate this from your data, you could do...

```
$colors = preg_replace('/<br\s?\/?>/', "\n", $colors);
```

Double encode just means things like `&amp;amp;` won't happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I was actually about to do. I'm going to mark @El Yobo's as correct based on the order answered :P